# UICollectionView in iOS 10 is misaligning cells

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, ios10

I have a collection view that used to look like this (iOS 9-):

[image: Correctly (and previously) displayed UICollectionView]

As of iOS 10 however, that exact same untouched collection view is displaying like this:

[image: Incorrectly displayed UICollectionView as of iOS 10]

No constraints or anything really have been changed from iOS 9 to iOS 10. I simply cannot figure out what the issue is. If it helps, the only constraints on this collection view are 0 spacing stuck to top, left, right and bottom:

[image]

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was I forgot to add constraints for the containing view. Fixed.